How is it that I can simultaneously be both a participant and an observer?
I have a dual consciousness, as if I chose to be an observer of the human experience, with the ability to immerse and participate whenever I wish. I was born this way, as if I am an observing consciousness witnessing the human experience from both inside and outside at the same time. How can this state be explained?

Do you know the name of this condition?

As it stands this sounds like a question for (maybe) the psychology SE. Or Buddhist...Hindu... where ppl practice meditation to(wards) making this kind of state the norm/default

If this is a persistent experienced condition, I would suggest talking to a psychotherapist (or reading pyschotherapeutic lit at least), or talking face-to-face to others about it. This condition can lead to/strengthen feelings of alienation and inability to actually feel a rapport with others.

I was born this way and I have no connection to the religions you mentioned, nor do I practice meditation at all.

Isn't everybody this way?

@JonathanZ Some people stay immersed and never individuate.

You ask, “How can this state be explained?” What would (for you) constitute an explanation?

I tend to agree with @JonathanZ that you are simply a bit more self-aware, or are simply paying a bit more attention to that self-awareness, then most. It is hard to be sentient without having a model of self, which allows us to watch ourselves think. Or at least watch the model of ourselves think.
If it is interfering with life, then yes, it may be worth consulting psychological or psychiatric experts to develop coping skills and/or adjust baseline biochemistry.
If it isn't having undesirable effects, then the best strategy may be to simply accept it.

Ordinarily, from birth one is immersed in family and close groups of people whom one may barely differentiate oneself from; an instinctive tribal unity. As one's mind develops it needs to take space for itself to deliberate and may eventually fully self-actualise or 'individuate'.  There, for example, are two modes such as the OP describes: immersive or 'observant'.

I guess the OP's distinction is that even though they've individuated they can still re-immerse in that un-individuated state when they want to?

@JonathanZ Yes, reimmerse in a game, forget yourself having fun. No probs.

Well, at least no probs for the ones having fun.

My experience is completely different. I suffer from dual consciousness, where I live in a state of observation and contemplation of myself and my human experience at the same

@HameedAhmed Do you sometime forget to observe when contemplating intently?

Ah, you're suffering from this state? You could try the occasional alcoholic drink.

Yes but I don't drink alcohol

It might attenuate the suffering.
